# Standalone crops arrowhead and border does not show in parent file

Tags: tikz-arrows, standalone

**Problem:**

Arrowheads are cutoff in a `tikzpicture` environment in a `standalone` and the parent file that calls the standalone. I've tried using a border, but that only seems to rectify the issue in the standalone, but not in the parent class. Similar questions on Stack Overflow don't seem to make mention of a solution to this, or this being a problem that cannot simply be solved with a border. How might I go about approaching this problem correctly?

**MWE:**

**Standalone File:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1in]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1in}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->] (0, 0) -- (2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Parent File:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, standalone}

\begin{document}
    \includestandalone{image}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image: Out with cropped arrowheads, border disregarded]

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` to both files. I recall this question being asked before but I cannot locate it now.

Comment: @Ross No luck. Added it to both the standalone and the main file; both still show up cropped.